# Lotus Domino: View pagination on web

Tags: view, pagination, lotus-domino

I read on many forums about how to implement a solution for view pagionation, but I didn't solve it.

I created `$$ViewTemplateDefault` containing some personalized hotspotbuttons for `Next`, `Previous` and a text field `$$ViewBody`. ( or, alternatively, an embedded view ).

Any tips and help will be really appreciated.

I will explain in a couple words, just to be clear:

So, initially: the first 30 lines will appear => in a right corner: Page 1.

If Next is clicked => the next 30 lines => Page 2. and so on.

Comment: What did you put in your hotspot buttons for Next and Previous? What happens when you click them?  Have you looked at anyone else's code? There are lots of samples that you can look at -- for example the view templates in the standard discussion template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My view is listing 30 lines per time. Next => the next 30 lines. Analogically, the previous button.

Comment: That's the normal default behavior.  If you want it to do something different, then you need to re-write your question and tell us what you want it to do instead; and you need to show us what you have tried and tell us what happened. Please review the guidelines on how to ask good questions here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't think the pagination on a view under the web is a normal default behavior. If it is so, could you tell me how it works? Exactly, I don't think you know. A good day and good luck with pointing -1 to the questions you don't know the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't believe me, but 30 lines per view is definitely the default behavior of the Domino web server.  You can change that default by going to the Web Engine tab in the Server document in the Domino Directory on the server and changing the field labeled 'Default lines per view page'. On some servers, that setting might be elsewhere - i.e., in an Internet Sites document. There is also a setting for the maximum number of entries displayed per view, and you can set it to zero -- but that affects all views in all databases on the server.

Comment: BTW: I admit that I'm not up to speed on the latest Domino stuff becuase I haven't worked with it much in the last two years, but the Domino web engine's view rendering logic goes back to about 1997. Still, if you don't trust me... perhaps you will trust the author of this article: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/EPSD-4YLQZ5  It tells you how to change both the default and the maximum number of lines per page of a view. It even tells you how to get Domino to render an unlimited number of lines per view, but it warns about the performance impact.

Comment: And if that's what you really wanted (i.e., getting Domino to stop paginating your view, and just render all lines on one page), then change your question to actually say that.  If you do that, I will remove my downvote. Or if that's not what you really want, then I'm sorry but you still haven't made yourself clear so edit your question and try again to say exactly what you want. I will remove my downvote when you've made it clear.

Comment: Richard, I thought you suggest that pagination is the default behavior. I know that if you set a unlimited number of lines/view will affect the server performance. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution for categorized views too. It calculates the current page number based on the previous page number and uses cookies.

Add to your form a Path-Thru HTML text `<span id="pageNumber"></span >` for the page number:

[image]

and add following code to form's `onLoad` event as Web/JavaScript:

```
function getURLParameter(parameter) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + parameter + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
function compareStart(start1, start2) {
    var list1 = start1.split(".");
    var list2 = start2.split(".");
    for (i=0; i <100; i++) {
        var value1 = list1[i];
        var value2 = list2[i];
        if (value1 == null) {
            return value2 == null ? 0 : -1;
        } else if (value2 == null) {
                return 1;
        }
        value1 = Math.round(value1);
        value2 = Math.round(value2);
        if (value1 !== value2) {
            return value1 < value2 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
}
var start = getURLParameter("Start");
var page = "1";
if  (start == null || start === "1") {
    window.name = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
    start = "1";
} else {
    page =  getCookie("page" + window.name);
    var oldStart = getCookie("start" + window.name);
    page = Math.round(page) + compareStart(start, oldStart);
}
document.getElementById('pageNumber').innerHTML = page;
document.cookie = "page" + window.name + "=" + page;
document.cookie = "start" + window.name + "=" + start;
```

*How does it work?*

The commands `@DbCommand("Domino"; "ViewNextPage")` and `@DbCommand("Domino"; "ViewPreviousPage")` return an URL with parameter "&Start=". This is the row number in view where the current page starts. For categorized views they return a hierarchical number like "&Start=1.2.4.2". That means that the view starts at the first main topic, subtopic 2, subsubtopic 4, document 2.

This parameter "&Start=" gives us the possibility to recognize if user pressed "prev" or "next": we just compare the URL "&Start=" parameter of current and former page.

For that, we have to remember the URL "&Start=" parameter and put it into a cookie "start".

We also need to save the current page number. We put it into a cookie "page".

At `onload` event we calculate the current page number based on previous page number:

- if "&Start=" parameter is larger now then we add 1
- if "&Start=" parameter is smaller now then we subtract 1
- if "&Start=" parameter didn't change then we keep the former value

If "&Start=" parameter is empty we know we are on page 1.

Here is one other thing we have to deal with: cookies are saved per user session not per browser tab. That means, if we have two views open in browser same cookies "start" and "page" would be used. To avoid that, we have to add to cookie name something tab specific. I use for that a random four digit number and save it in `window.name` which is tab specific.

Comment: Could you tell me, please, how to instert a Path-Thru HTML text on a form?

Comment: Write the text into form, mark the text and click menu "Text / Path-Thru HTML"

Comment: It works! Amazing! I observed that it works even if you are having the app opened in 2 different tabs of window.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ( again ) Now I have to study the code from OnLoad event.

Comment: About the cookies, a (silly) question: If the cookies, let say, are deleted, while the app runs on a web, it still works?

Comment: The code doesn't depends on how many lines ( in my case: 30 ) are listed on the view, right?

Comment: No, the number of lines doesn't matter. Code just uses start parameter  to decide was it a prev or next turn.

Comment: Your question about cookies: just try what happens. The worst thing that could happen is page number is not shown. But how cookies are might be deleted during the session and by whom?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you have a working form $$ViewTemplateDefault and now looking for a possibility to show the current page number "Page nn" in that form.

I assume that you use `@DbCommand("Domino"; "ViewNextPage")` for getting next page and `@DbCommand("Domino"; "ViewPreviousPage")` for getting previous page.

Those next and prev functions working the way that always one document will "overlap". If you have 30 lines per page and click next, then last document will be first in next page and next 29 show up in addition. You can watch that in used URL parameter "&Start=": 1 ... 30 ... 59 ... 88 ...

Knowing this you can count the current page number this way:

```
_start := @ToNumber(@Replace(@UrlQueryString("start"); ""; "1"));
_count := @ToNumber(@Replace(@UrlQueryString("count"); ""; "30")) - 1;
@Integer((@ToNumber(_start) / _count) + 1)
```

Be aware that this will work for non-categorized and non-collapsible views only.

A more sophisticated solution you can find [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/A-simpler-pagination-view-for-Lotus-Notes-documents-on-the-Web). It has additional features like GoTo page and Documents per page.

If you have the chance for your project then use XPages instead. You can do pagination much easier as it is available "out of the box".

**Update:**

You **won't** find a reasonable solution for categorized views. If you don't want to use [Domino Data/Access Services](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html) REST API you have to live with the Domino view URL parameters (look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_SERVERS_DATABASES_AND_VIEWS.html) for "OpenView"). You aren't able to tell from "&Start=" or any other parameter on which page you are currently on.

The easiest way to get a good working pagination is using XPages. Hope you are allowed to use it in your project...

Comment: Thanks for your response.unfortunately, i'm using categorized views ;(. Also, my URL, when I click Next/Previous, doesn't show the &Start variable.

Comment: @DbCommand("Domino";"ViewNextPage");
@SetTargetFrame("Myframe")

Comment: You have to test it without a frameset to see the OpenView URL parameters - just open a view in browser and reduce Next/Previous buttons to @DbCommand().

Comment: I tested it but it opens the view in another tab of browser. Considering this, I thought to use @SetTargetFrame...

Comment: Open the view in Designer at menu "Design / Preview in Web Browser / ...". You should see then an URL like `http://Server/Database.nsf/ViewName?OpenView` in your browser.

Comment: We already put the app on a local server. And when I click Next / Previous it doesn't show the start variable in the URL, just oursever.local.com/Database.nsf all the time.

Comment: That is because your view is still running in a frameset. Did you previewed the view *from Designer* like I described two comments ago?

Comment: It gives me an error like could not find the server... even I opened it from the designer

Comment: Then write URL `http://oursever.local.com/Database.nsf/ViewName?OpenView` manuelly in browser.

Comment: I write it. Because the view is categorized I get something like: &Start=1.2.4.2.1

Comment: Perfect! ... and "&Start=1.2.4.2.1" is the reason why you don't get a clue what start row you are currently on in view. But, for calculating the current page number you need to know the current row number. That's why I am saying no chance to get a solution for pagination using Domino view URLs.

Comment: You can work with REST API as an alternative but XPages would be much easier.

Comment: "&Start=1.2.4.2.1" means the view starts at the first main topic, subtopic 2, subsubtopic 4, subsubsubtopic 2, document 1. There is no way to recalculate this to a view's row number, unfortunately.

Comment: ;( Thanks for your help, so, in this case - as the view is categorized, "&Start=" is like @DocNumber used in a column view, right?