# Lotus Notes: view opened from outline in new tab on web

Tags: view, frame, lotus-notes

I have an outline which contains some outline entries.

Every entry contains a view and in the outline entry properties at Content there is the name of the frame. Also, every view in its properties at Auto Frame (web only), there is the name of the frame.

Even so, when I click another view to open it, it will b open in a new tab of the browser.

I appreciate your time and help!

PS: I observed this problem after I put the suggestion code ( which it works ): [Lotus Domino: View pagination on web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132262/lotus-domino-view-pagination-on-web) .

If I remove the code from `OnLoad` it works quite well, with no openings in new tab. Is there any chance to have the code on `OnLoad` event and the views to be open in same frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the value of window.name, the pagination code is affecting the name of the frame in which the content appears. So when you click a link in the outline, the browser goes to look for the window/frame with the name specified by the outline, and it can't find such a one -- so it opens a new window with the specified name.

For the pagination code to not interfere with your navigation, you would have to change it to not rename the window -- it would have to store its window-identifier elsewhere. For instance, if you know the view will appear in a frameset, you could set a property of **top** instead of **window**. Since the top window of the frameset doesn't change when you load new pages within a frame, you can even just keep track of the last Start= parameter there, and not bother with cookies.

I encourage you to look into using XPages for your web design -- this is usually simpler.

Comment: Btw, I never worked before using XPages, but I would like to learn. Can you suggest a good documentation?

Comment: You can find a lot of information about XPages here http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Home.xsp ("Get Started", Resources, ...)